# shared preference + firebase auth not working properly

Tags: flutter, authentication

Firebase Auth is working properly, I'm able to log in, Sign in but I want to preserve the state of the application. For state persistence, I'm using Share preferences.

- I'm using sharedpreferences. I made a class and defined some keys and methods to fetch and set the data in the keys at the time of login and use it later in the app.
- Please help me out with an easy approch how to do this.

````
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    
    class CurrentUser {
      static SharedPreferences? mypreferences;
      static const emailKey = 'emailKey';
      static const passwordKey = 'paswordKey';
      static const loginStatusKey = 'loginStatusKey';
    
      static Future init() async {
        mypreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
       
      }
    
      static Future setUserEmail(String? emailValue) async {
        return await mypreferences?.setString(emailKey, emailValue!);
      } 
    
      static Future setUserPassword(String? passwordValue) async {
        return await mypreferences?.setString(passwordKey, passwordValue!);
      }
    
       static Future setLoginStatus(bool status) async {
        return await mypreferences?.setBool(loginStatusKey, status);
      }
    
      static String? getUserEmail() {
        return  mypreferences?.getString(emailKey);
      }
    
      static String? getUserPassword() {
        return  mypreferences?.getString(passwordKey);
      }
    
      static bool? getUserLoginStatus(){
        if(loginStatusKey==null){
          mypreferences?.setBool(loginStatusKey, false);
        }
        return mypreferences?.getBool(loginStatusKey);
      }
    }```
    // storing the value during login //
    
    ``` myLogIn() async {
        try {
          UserCredential myuser= await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
          // print(myuser);
          // print(myuser.user?.email);
          CurrentUser.setUserEmail(myuser.user?.email);
          CurrentUser.setUserPassword(password);
          CurrentUser.setLoginStatus(true);
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, MyRoutes.homeRoute);
          
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
            print('user is not registered');
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                MySnackBar.showcustomSnackbar('user is not registered'));
          } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
            print('wrong password');
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(MySnackBar.showcustomSnackbar('wrong password'));
          }
        }
      }```
    // using the store login status in main file to show login page and home page accordingly.
    
    ```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    // import 'firebase_options.dart';
    
    import './pages/login.dart';
    import './pages/signup.dart';
    import './pages/homepage.dart';
    import './utils/my_theme.dart';
    import './utils/my_routes.dart';
    import './pages/forgot_password.dart';
    import './utils/my_user.dart';
    
    void main() {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      CurrentUser.init();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      // const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
      final Future<FirebaseApp> initializeMyFirebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp();
    
       bool? isLogin = CurrentUser.getUserLoginStatus();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        isLogin = CurrentUser.getUserLoginStatus();
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: initializeMyFirebaseApp,
            builder: (context, snaphot) {
              //Error checking
              if (snaphot.hasError) {
                print("Something went wrong!");
              }
              //If snapshot state is in waiting or so
              if (snaphot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              //else we will show the normal login page.
              return MaterialApp(
                theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context),
                //isUserLoggedIn !=null ? isUserLoggedIn ? Home() : SignUp() : SignIn(),
                home:isLogin!=null ? 
                isLogin! ? HomePage() : Login() : Login(),
                // Login(),
                routes: {
                  // "/":(context) => Login(),
                  MyRoutes.loginRoute: (context) => Login(),
                  MyRoutes.signupRoute: (context) => SignUp(),
                  MyRoutes.homeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),
                  MyRoutes.forgotpasswordRoute: (context) => ForgotPassword(),
                },
              );
            });
      }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: I don't get where the problem is. Do you get any error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.